# Get integer value from Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
$qrtaskdeviceid =  DB::table('qrtasks_devices')
            ->select('id')
            ->Where('deviceid', $pumpid)
            ->Where('devicetype', 'pump')
            ->get();
```

returns: [{"id":4}]

I tried almost everything to get "4", but I failed:

```
$qrtaskdeviceid->id
$qrtaskdeviceid->pluck('id')
$qrtaskdeviceid[id]
$qrtaskdeviceid->first();
```

...

I also checked on stackoverflow and google, but I could not find a source that could answer this small problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are want single result use `->first()` instead `->get();`

And use `$qrtaskdeviceid->id` to get result id.

In your current result use `$qrtaskdeviceid[0]->id`

Answer (score 5):

For Laravel 5.3 and up you can use `value()` to get single value from query

```
$qrtaskdeviceid =  DB::table('qrtasks_devices')
            ->select('id')
            ->Where('deviceid', $pumpid)
            ->Where('devicetype', 'pump')
            ->value('id');
```